# Hide Organization / Project Settings using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

How can I as an admin of a project at Azure DevOps disable or hide Organizational / Project Settings options for users who are contributors of a particular project? This is for security purposes so that contributors do not play around with settings. Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to create a group for this contributors and then restrict the permission of that group?

Comment: The Contributor Group was already created, I just add members to the Group.

Comment: so restricting the access of that group does not work?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I as an admin of a project at Azure DevOps disable or hide
> Organizational / Project Settings options for users who are
> contributors of a particular project?

You can disable to editing permission of settings(this can make sure the users unable to play around with settings), but it is impossible to hide the UI.

For every users to want to limit, use these setting:

[image]

In this situation, they will be unable to edit the settings.

By the way, the PCA(Project Collection Administrators) is very special, if a user has this permission, other settings will not overwrite this.

Comment: Hello- Thank you for the help. I logged on as the admin and the in the Organizational Settings selected the Permission option, then selected the Project, then members. Selected a member and set the mentioned permission to denied. Asked the user to logout, clear the cache and login again, but still both options i.e. Organizational settings and Project Settings were still there

Comment: @TayyabHussain Hi, "You can disable to editing permission of settings(this can make sure the users unable to play around with settings), but it is impossible to hide the UI. There is currently no such feature to hide the project settings and organization settings."    Does this clearly for you to explain and answer your question?